# C# array with capacity over Int.MaxValue

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I was wondering if there is any structure in C# that can contain more than Int.MaxValue's restriction of 2,147,483,647 items, in case of really large sets of information. Would this have to be done with multi level arrays? Or could you create an array that has a maximum length of Long.MaxValue? If so, how?

Comment: If you're planning on creating arrays of this size, you should probably reconsider your approach.

Comment: Looking to build the next Twitter?

Comment: Multilevel arrays could do the trick, but there's the risk of running out of memory. What do you need it for?

Comment: I was looking for a solution for holding the data of the Bible in a Array or list, but it looks like I wont be able to have all the information I wanted...because I needed literally a element for every greek word, every hebrew word, every word in english's strong number, if it's highlighted, etc

Comment: A database solution is far more likely to be the way to go. For that matter, breaking things down to the word level is unusual (except for some Qaballic ways of studying the Hebrew), as you'll then lose the connection between the different verses, as the translations are not 1-1 on words, but are 1-1 on verses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been done, a sample `BigArray<T>` implementation [is here](http://web.archive.org/web/20151010222722/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx).

Comment: Cool! Thanks for giving me the link to this!

Answer (score 6):

The CLR currently has a limit of 2GB for any single object - so you'd have to build it out of multiple arrays, even for an element type of `byte`. That should be feasible though. Most of the normal collection interfaces would fail as they use `int` for the index, count etc.

I *believe* the CLR itself isn't restricted to an overall process limit which would prevent this - although you'd almost certainly want to be running on a 64-bit CLR and OS, of course.

Comment: Which is all a bit odd since there's an overload of GetValue on System.Array that takes a long as index suggesting that you could have way larger arrays (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zexc3z9.aspx)

Comment: @Rune: Yes - I agree it's very odd. A bit of premature design, potentially.

Comment: @LukeH - yes and that's the odd part when they don't add anything (except for misleading the unfortunate) why add them at all. Adding them when they would actually be supported would not be a breaking change. (Removing them no of course would)

Comment: `private readonly int[] _arrInts = new int[IntMax];` throws an System.OutOfMemoryException. Where as `private const int IntMax = int.MaxValue;`. Any idea why?

Comment: @barnes: Well that's trying to create an array that's 8GB in size... I believe there's a setting that gets over the 2GB limit now, but whether it will allow an 8GB array, I don't know...

Comment: Got it. Thanks :).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Not anymore: `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` allows to create arrays greater than 2GB, although still the usual CLR array limits remain (per dimension not more than 2146435071 elements, 2147483591 in case the element consists of only 1 byte, not more that 4294967295 elements in total over all dimensions).

Comment: @Christoph: Indeed, things change a lot in 11 years...

Answer (score 4):

What is your requirement?  It's hard to believe that an array with more elements than this is going to be the correct solution for any real-world problem, irrespective of whether it's legal or not. You may be thinking of a database here, whether persisted or in-memory. That's the standard means for organizing very large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

You could only use an index based structure if the indexer was a `long` (int64) rather than an `int32`.

Even a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) wouldn't work as the indexer is an `int32`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought...oh well, looks like I need to cut back on the information.

Answer (score 1):

Very little computers will have enough memory to hold such structure in-memory.

Comment: @SLaks, then maybe I should add: very little computers will handle such structure in-memory.

Comment: `private readonly int[] _arrInts = new int[IntMax];` throws a `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Where `private const int IntMax = int.MaxValue;`. Any idea why?

Answer (score -2):

ArrayList can contain more than Int.MaxValue.

Comment: Nope, it cannot, because the constructor takes only an integer for capacity, and thus cannot be more than Int32.MaxValue

Comment: @Richard: Your logic isn't *completely* sound, as the capacity increases automatically. You could provide `int.MaxValue` and then add more items. I'm pretty sure ArrayList would still fail, but not just because you couldn't specify the *final* capacity to the constructor as the *initial* capacity.